# How can I transfer unconfirmed transactions from wallet.dat to a new blockchain wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, unconfirmed-transactions, hash, wallet.dat, transaction-id

My question may not be very clear since I’m not really an expert in bitcoin and its technology. But in my possession I have just a wallet.dat files with an unconfirmed transaction on it.

I followed a procedure of spending the unconfirmed Bitcoin from the wallet.dat wallet into a new blockchain wallet address.

At this level I have linked the wallet.dat with my bitcoin core, and even checked the wallet.dat balance on bitref and it shows the bitcoins is unspent but unconfirmed.

This is where I’m confused

- available balance on my Bitcoin core is 0.00000 and blocks not yet fully syncd.
- I tried using the JSON process of spending the bitcoins into a new blockchain wallet, after putting all I was asked in the process I got what you will see below.

E2 -> Error Parse error on line ‘1’ parse error on line^
Expecting‘STRING’, ‘NUMBER’, ‘NULL’, ‘TRUE’, ‘FALSE’
‘{‘, ‘[‘, got ‘undefined

And left me with no option than OK.
My bitcoin core version is 0.19.0.1

I don’t know if my question does makes sense but that’s what I’m facing please some should help me

Comment: You've sent funds to a Bitcoin Core receiving address and then discovered that Bitcoin Core is NOT the wallet that you really want to use. Either because it takes a better part of a week to sync the blockchain or you just don't like the wallet.
You don't want to wait for a full synchronization of the blockchain before transferring your funds
Here is the procedure in a nutshell:
Install a new bitcoin wallet (like BitPay)
Open Bitcoin Core
Open the debug console inside Bitcoin Core
Gather some information
Create a raw transaction
Sign the raw transaction
Broadcast the raw transaction

Comment: I tried the above procedure and got this E2 -> Error Parse error on line ‘1’ parse error on line^ Expecting‘STRING’, ‘NUMBER’, ‘NULL’, ‘TRUE’, ‘FALSE’ ‘{‘, ‘[‘, got ‘undefined

At the level of opening the "load url" and put in:   https://insight.bitpay.com/api/tx/<txid>